# REGEXP to NOT match if there is a hyphen before a variable

Tags: mysql, regex

I am having a hard time correctly matching a variable ($myvar) using MySQL REGEX.

My first thought was to match the word (\b), but this will match both "testtype" and "edit-testtype" in my example below, which I don't want:

```
SELECT "edit-testtype, themes, upload, plugin-editor" REGEXP '\\b$myvar\\b';
```

After a lot of internet searching I thought I had the answer with this:

```
SELECT "edit-testtype, themes, upload, plugin-editor" REGEXP '\^(?!-)\\b$myvar\\b';
```

but it will fail on any of the other words in the string. I guess what I need is a REGEX that will NOT match any $myvar that is preceded by a hyphen/dash.

Comment: have you tried escaping the $

Comment: $myvar is just a stand in for any variable text, it is not actually sent.

Comment: Why not use [`find_in_set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). You only need to make sure to have no spaces after the commas... but for the rest it seems to be what you need, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to try a regex way, you may use

```
REGEXP CONCAT('(^|[^-])[[:<:]]', $myvar', '($|[[:>:]][^-])')
```

This won't work if your`$myvar` contains special chars like `[`, `(`, `+` - they would need to be escaped.

Note that `(^|[^-])` matches the start of string or a non-hyphen, `[[:<:]]` matches a leading word boundary and `[[:>:]]` matches the trailing word boundary.

The `($|[[:>:]][^-])` part matches 2 alternatives: either the end of string (`$`) or a trailing word boundary plus a character other than a hyphen.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using this: REGEXP (^|[^-])\b'.$myvar.'\b($|[^-])

Comment: In MySQL, a `\b` does not denote a word boundary. See [this reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp).

Comment: FYI, that is part of a wordpress meta query, it translates the \b to \\b when it sends it to MySQL, and it works.

Comment: GAH! This works in MariaDB, but NOT MySQL. Thanks for the heads up, my local testing db was MariaDB.

Comment: on MySQL but succeeds on MariaDB: `SELECT "edit-testtype, themes, upload, plugin-editor" REGEXP '(^|[^-])[[:<:]]plugin-editor[[:>:]]($|[^-])';` It seems MySQL does not like this if there is no space at the end...do you have any suggestions for getting this to work if my variable is the last item with no space at the end of the field? Thanks!

Comment: That makes no sense. Word boundary and the end of string anchor are zero width assertions and require no space after the last character to match. Try replacing `[[:>:]]($|[^-])` with `($|[[:>:]][^-])`.

Comment: I implemented your feedback into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

http://regexr.com/3do1b

Try this regex: `^[^-]+$`

I haven't tested this.

Comment: could not get this to work, could you include the entire select query?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regular expression (example with `edit-testtype`):

```
(^|, )edit-testtype(,|$)
```

But as you are essentially trying to find an element in a comma-separated list, you could use [`find_in_set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
select find_in_set($myvar, "edit-testtype,themes,upload,plugin-editor") > 0
```

You just need to make sure not to have spaces after the commas. If you cannot change that, use a plain replace on it:

```
replace("edit-testtype, themes, upload, plugin-editor", ", ", ",")
```

... before applying `find_in_set()`.